# How to check thread priority of a random process?

Tags: windows, process

In Windows Task Manager I can set (or when I right click I can view) the process priority. Is shows "real time", "high", "above normal", etc. The same goes for the "ProcessExplorer" (from sysinternals, now microsoft). The question is: Is there a way to see what threads are running with what priorities in a given process? (along with a number, which is from 0 to 31, I think). So that would be 32 priority levels, not just 5 level. (6,7,8,9,10)

---

*Full disclaimer: I've already posted this question on stackoverflow, however it was suggested that this belongs on superuser, so I marked it to delete it since no one was able to give me an answer.*

---

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, I found it. In the ProcessExplorer you can right click on the process, select properties. From there, select Threads Tab, it shows all the threads running inside the process with "dynamic priorities".
That's what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Turn on the 'Priority' column in process explorer's main window. On my system (which has nothing running as realtime), I'm seeing priorities from 0-13, so I think it's reading the actual priority.

Do this by right-clicking on the column headers, then select 'Select Columns...' from the pop-up menu, then under 'process performance' select priority.

Comment: Sorry, but you're talking about process priority and I was looking for thread priority inside the process. Those are not the same.

Comment: Yup, you're right. And I see that you've already found it.